Seperate URLS from input field's value before sending as email message NEXTJS
I am currently using react-hook-forms and nodemailer for a contest form which allows a user to upload files and then the urls from an array are set as values for an input field.
Problem is, when data from the input field is taken and used by nodemailer to be sent as an part of an email message, the urls are all strings that are concatenated and all of them will have a combined URL when clicked, hence a wrong a link.
How do you go about separating the concatenated urls and each will have their own url in the email message?
